MYSQL Authentication Error
I have a MYSQl Database hosted by our ocal ISP. IT recently crashed and they attempted to recover what they could from the VM.However, on core application (a Student Reporting System) fails to authenticate users to this day.
I copied the entire database and rebuild it on my localhost and voila!! It works perfectly. Xamp with Apache 2.4.58 (Win64) PHP8.0.3 PhpMyAdin 5.21.
When I restore to the Hosting Server all authentication just fails.
Will appreciate more probing questions and assitance where neccesary.

all authentication just fails, what error is thrown ?

Is the situation that you able to connect from phpMyAdmin to the database but any user accounts in your application, and/or are you unable to even connect to the database itself?

I would like to suggest a few steps to help recover your MySQL database:
Make sure to back up your MySQL files, especially the .ibd files, before proceeding with recovery.
Check MySQL Logs:
Review the MySQL error logs (/var/log/mysql/error.log) for clues about the cause of the failure and the specific corrupted files.
Rebuild the Table Structure (If Possible):
If you know the table structure, recreate the tables in MySQL and import the data from the .ibd files.
Attach .ibd Files to New Tables:
If you have the .ibd files, you can try to reattach them by creating a new table with the same structure and using the following commands:
ALTER TABLE table_name DISCARD TABLESPACE;
ALTER TABLE table_name IMPORT TABLESPACE;
Use Recovery Tools:
If manual methods don’t work, try a tool like Stellar Repair for MySQL, which can recover data from .ibd files, even without the table structures.
Check for Backups:
If you have any recent backups, restoring from them might be the quickest way to get back up and running.
I hope this helps!

How will this be of help? (After reading: "I copied the entire database and rebuild it on my localhost and voila!! It works perfectly.")
